# Android Custom View Absolute Positioning

Tags: android

My question is rather straightforward. I have a custom view (a rectangle), that will be rotated, translated, and scaled ontop of its parent view (RelativeLayout).

My question is what is the best way to handle these transformations. Should I:
A: Modify the CustomView's draw() and apply canvas transformations
B: Modify the LayoutParams margin for left and top.
C: Pursue an alternate approach, given my problem set.

The rest of the problem set looks like this.
1. The Custom View must be able to overlap other custom views and be able to be drawn outside the bounds of its parent view.
2. A 4 point path is generated overtop the CustomView's drawable that represents its collision volume. This collision volume is synchronized with the rotation and translation of the View by modifying a Matrix object that is then applied on top of the volume in order to accurately handle collisions and avoid false positives.
3. This custom view object will be animated using standard AnimationTranslate, AnimationRotate, AnimationScale functionality. After the animation completes the original View will be transposed to its computed location postAnimation.

Thank You for your time experts

Answer (score 0):

you can read more about property animation here http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/animation-in-honeycomb.html

Comment: Thank you, but my question wasn't regarding animations but view transformations vs margin offsets.